# Proving a combinatorial identity

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following identity combinatorially:

$\sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{k} \binom{n+k}{m} = \sum_{k=0}^m \binom{m}{m-k} \binom{n}{k}2^k$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine two towers, the left one with $m$ levels and the right one with $n$ levels.  We want to put one-way ladders between the towers, such that each ladder connects a single level of the left tower to a single level of the right tower.  Ladders are not allowed to cross each other--i.e. ladder $i+1$ connects levels of the two towers which are strictly higher than those connected by ladder $i$.  How many ways can we do this?

One way to count the arrangements of ladders is to pick $k$ levels from both towers to be connected.  By the no-crossing requirement for the ladders, the $i$-th highest level of each tower are connected to each other, and there are two ways to run each ladder.  So the number of ways to have $k$ ladders is $\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}2^k$.  Summing over all possible numbers of ladders gives the right hand side of the desired expression.

Another way to count the arrangements of ladders is to first pick $m-k$ levels of the left tower that will have *outgoing* ladders (rather than incoming ladders or no ladders).  Then of the $n$ levels on the right tower and the $k$ unselected levels on the left tower, you choose $m$ of them, with the following interpretation:

- Levels selected on the left tower are those that have no ladders to them.
- Levels selected on the right tower are those that *do* have ladders going to them.

Any levels on the left tower that are not among the original $m-k$ levels nor among the later $m$ levels will have *incoming* ladders.

You can convince yourself that this procedure uniquely identifies all possible ways of stringing ladders between the two towers, with $m-k$ ladders outgoing from the left tower.  The number of ways to do this is $\binom{m}{m-k}\binom{n+k}{m} = \binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{m}$.  Summing over all $k$ gives the left hand side of the desired expression.